# How I can show custom error message for the Internet Calendar Subscription api

Tags: outlook, calendar, icalendar, subscription

I have created a Internet Calendar Subscription where it checks if there is any event then it returns otherwise it returns with a response message.

```
{
"message": "There are no events available for the specified timeframe.",
"status": "no_data"
```

}

Now when outlook make a request to the endpoint for the events it do not get the events and it displays a common task error message.

[image]

Being a user of this service or outlook, I do not know what is the reason of failure, why I do not get the response or events. Is there anyway that the responded message keeps appear in this task window so that user has an idea there is no event for now.

Please help if there is any explicit response pattern needed to be followed then I can update.